# Winforms bindingsource issue adding new record

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset, bindingsource

I have the following code to load an bind data to master-detail window, where master data bound to textboxes and other controls and detail data bound to DataGridView:

ON FORM LOAD:

```
    DataSet dsOrders = new DataSet("dsOrders");

            SqlDataAdapter daOrderHeader;// = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlDataAdapter daOrderDetail;// = new SqlDataAdapter();

            BindingSource bsOrderHeader = new BindingSource();
            BindingSource bsOrderDetail = new BindingSource();

    DataTable dtOrderHeader = new DataTable("dtOrderHeader");
                DataTable dtOrderDetail = new DataTable("dtOrderDetail");

                dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtOrderHeader);
                dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtOrderDetail);

                daOrderHeader = DataAdapterOrderHeader();
                daOrderDetail = DataAdapterOrderDetail();

                daOrderHeader.Fill(dtOrderHeader);
                daOrderDetail.Fill(dtOrderDetail);

                ////Set up a master-detail relationship between the DataTables
                DataColumn keyOrderHeaderColumn = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].Columns["ID"];
                DataColumn foreignKeyOrderDetailColumn = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"].Columns["OrderId"];
                dsOrders.Relations.Add("rOrders", keyOrderHeaderColumn, foreignKeyOrderDetailColumn);

                bsOrderHeader.DataSource = dsOrders;
                bsOrderHeader.DataMember = "dtOrderHeader";
                bsOrderDetail.DataSource = bsOrderHeader;
                bsOrderDetail.DataMember = "rOrders";

tbxOrderNo.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "ID");
            tbxCustomer.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "Name");
            tbxTaxRate.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "TaxRate");
            tbxShipping.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "Shipping");
            tbxExchangeRate.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "ExchangeRate");
            dtpOrderDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "OrderDate");
            cbxPriceCode.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", bsOrderHeader, "PriceCode");
            dgvItems.DataSource = bsOrderDetail;

enter code here
```

ON ADD NEW RECORD:

```
DataRow drOrderHeader = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].NewRow();
            drOrderHeader["ID"] = (maxID + 1);
            dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].Rows.Add(drOrderHeader);
            DataRow drOrderDetail = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"].NewRow();
            drOrderDetail["OrderId"] = (maxID + 1);
            dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"].Rows.Add(drOrderDetail);
            bsOrderHeader.DataSource = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"];
            bsOrderDetail.DataSource = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"];
```

When I click add new row button, bindingsource.count property shows that new record has been added, but winform controls stay on the same record and I am not able scroll to newly created record, also bindingsource.movelast stoped working.

Any suggestion please? What I need is to scroll to newly added record/row with all winform textboxes cleared and ready to enter data for new record, except OrderId that I generate and in this code at the time of creation

UPDATE: Made changes to Add button, but unsuccessfull

```
newOrderId = Convert.ToInt32(dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].Compute("max(ID)", string.Empty)) + 1;
            DataRow drOrderHeader = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].NewRow();
            drOrderHeader["ID"] = (newOrderId);
            dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].Rows.Add(drOrderHeader);
            DataRow drOrderDetail = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"].NewRow();
            drOrderDetail["OrderId"] = (newOrderId);
            dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"].Rows.Add(drOrderDetail);
            bsOrderHeader.Position = bsOrderHeader.Find("ID", newOrderId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found, data binding detects the changes you've made in the underlying data sources, thus the following two lines:

```
bsOrderHeader.DataSource = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"];
bsOrderDetail.DataSource = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"];
```

are redundant. And not only that, but the second changes incorrectly the data source type of the `bsOrderDetail`. So simply remove them.

In order to rebind the UI to the newly added record, all you need is to set the [`Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.position(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `bsOrderHeader` to the index of the new record like this:

```
bsOrderHeader.Position = bsOrderHeader.Find("ID", drOrderHeader["ID"]);
```

and the data binding infrastructure will automatically rebind both master controls and (via `DataRelation`) the detail grid view.

**EDIT:** Here is full working demo. If your code doesn't work after the update, it should be caused by some other code part not shown in the post.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();


            DataSet dsOrders = new DataSet("dsOrders");

            //SqlDataAdapter daOrderHeader;// = new SqlDataAdapter();
            //SqlDataAdapter daOrderDetail;// = new SqlDataAdapter();

            BindingSource bsOrderHeader = new BindingSource();
            BindingSource bsOrderDetail = new BindingSource();

            DataTable dtOrderHeader = new DataTable("dtOrderHeader");
            DataTable dtOrderDetail = new DataTable("dtOrderDetail");

            dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtOrderHeader);
            dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtOrderDetail);

            //daOrderHeader = DataAdapterOrderHeader();
            //daOrderDetail = DataAdapterOrderDetail();

            //daOrderHeader.Fill(dtOrderHeader);
            //daOrderDetail.Fill(dtOrderDetail);
            dtOrderHeader.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dtOrderHeader.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dtOrderHeader.Columns.Add("TaxRate", typeof(decimal));
            dtOrderHeader.Columns.Add("Shipping", typeof(string));
            dtOrderHeader.Columns.Add("ExchangeRate", typeof(decimal));
            dtOrderHeader.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dtOrderHeader.Columns.Add("PriceCode", typeof(int));

            dtOrderHeader.PrimaryKey = new[] { dtOrderHeader.Columns["ID"] };

            dtOrderDetail.Columns.Add("OrderId", typeof(int));
            dtOrderDetail.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(decimal));

            ////Set up a master-detail relationship between the DataTables
            DataColumn keyOrderHeaderColumn = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].Columns["ID"];
            DataColumn foreignKeyOrderDetailColumn = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"].Columns["OrderId"];
            var rel = dsOrders.Relations.Add("rOrders", keyOrderHeaderColumn, foreignKeyOrderDetailColumn);

            bsOrderHeader.DataSource = dsOrders;
            bsOrderHeader.DataMember = "dtOrderHeader";
            bsOrderDetail.DataSource = bsOrderHeader;
            bsOrderDetail.DataMember = "rOrders";

            var splitView = new SplitContainer { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            var tbxOrderNo = new TextBox();
            var tbxCustomer = new TextBox();
            var tbxTaxRate = new TextBox();
            var tbxShipping = new TextBox();
            var tbxExchangeRate = new TextBox();
            var dtpOrderDate = new DateTimePicker();
            int y = 8;
            foreach (var c in new Control[] { tbxOrderNo, tbxCustomer, tbxTaxRate, tbxShipping, tbxExchangeRate, dtpOrderDate })
            {
                c.Top = y;
                c.Left = 16;
                splitView.Panel1.Controls.Add(c);
                y = c.Bottom + 8;
            }

            var dgvItems = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = splitView.Panel2 };

            tbxOrderNo.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "ID");
            tbxCustomer.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "Name");
            tbxTaxRate.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "TaxRate");
            tbxShipping.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "Shipping");
            tbxExchangeRate.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "ExchangeRate");
            dtpOrderDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsOrderHeader, "OrderDate");
            //cbxPriceCode.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", bsOrderHeader, "PriceCode");
            dgvItems.DataSource = bsOrderDetail;


            Func<DataRow> addOrder = () =>
            {
                var maxOrderId = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].Compute("max(ID)", string.Empty);
                int newOrderId =  (maxOrderId != null && maxOrderId != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(maxOrderId) : 0) + 1;
                DataRow drOrderHeader = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].NewRow();
                drOrderHeader["ID"] = newOrderId;
                dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderHeader"].Rows.Add(drOrderHeader);
                DataRow drOrderDetail = dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"].NewRow();
                drOrderDetail["OrderId"] = newOrderId;
                dsOrders.Tables["dtOrderDetail"].Rows.Add(drOrderDetail);
                return drOrderHeader;
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) addOrder();

            var addButton = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Parent = form, Text = "Add" };
            addButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var drOrderHeader = addOrder();
                bsOrderHeader.Position = bsOrderHeader.Find("ID", drOrderHeader["ID"]);
            };

            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ivan, thanks for trying to help me. I have modified my code (see UPDATE), but I get the same result, it stays on the record it was on after I click my Add button and also bsOrderHeader.MoveLast stops working.

Comment: That's strange. See the edit and check the code not shown.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, it worked. I also had another problem, one of the controls on my form is a checkbox and another one combo box and they both have to have default value set in DataTable,(`dtOrderHeader.Columns["Paid"].DefaultValue = 0;
            dtOrderHeader.Columns["PriceCode"].DefaultValue = 0;`) until I fixed it it was breaking bindingsource navigation and wouldn't scroll to newly added records. Anyway thanks again, I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: I also had this problem.  A column bound to a CheckBox.Checked property.  My solution was to simply initialize the column values when adding rows.  Setting the DefaultValue per superconsultant methods works too.

Comment: The "no go" condition that occurs when trying to navigate to a record with invalid data (data not compatible with the bound controls) can be trapped by implementing a BindingSource.DataError event handler.